# Magento 2.1 php syntax error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php-7, xampp

I have run `php bin/magento` in command prompt then following error occurred:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in 
MyProjectPath\vendor\magento\magento-cloud-configuration\src\Magento\MagentoCloud\Console\Command\Deploy.php on line 538

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in D:\MyProjectPath\vendor\magento\magento-cloud-configuration\src\Magento\MagentoCloud\Console\Command\Deploy.php on line 538
```

I'm using php 7.02 (XAMPP version) according to the documentation.

I found `??`-syntax in Deploy.php which is supported by PHP7 in general.

Why does this error occur?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us that particular `line 538` and its surrounding.

Comment: It should work with PHP 7.0.x, please check your php version again. The same issue here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12645

Comment: Check your cli version. Maybe you use 7.0 for apache but 5.6 by default for cli. Open terminal and run php -v

Comment: @ Christoph Farnleitner   // MAGECLOUD-1317 avoid key collision on system between env.php and config.local.php
         $config['system']['default']['catalog']['search'] = array_replace_recursive(
            $config['system']['default']['catalog']['search'] ?? [],
            $this->getSearchEngineConfiguration()
         );

Comment: @ Furman yes you are correct its 5.6 but I have installed the 7.0.2 . cmd shows 5.6 . control panel shows original version ,